# in words -- meaning?

Tags: meaning

Example:

> The CREATE TABLE command has the following syntax:
>   *CREATE TABLE TableName
>
>       (ColumnDefinition, ...
>
>       [, Multi-ColumnConstraint, ...] );*
>   **In words**, the parameters to the CREATE TABLE statement are a table name, followed by one or more column definitions, followed by one or more (optional) multicolumn constraints. Note that the parentheses are also part of the syntax.

What is **in words** supposed to mean? Does that mean in real words, like, in plain English?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your understanding is correct.

The author explains the syntax of the `CREATE TABLE` command. First, they give the syntax of the command in [Structured Query Language (SQL)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL). Then, they explain the parameters of the command "in words". In other words, they explain the parameters in plain English, as opposed to in any other manners (such as in code, in figures, in diagrams, and so on).